# Can the label for a break have any name?

Tags: java, labeled-statements

I am learning java after coming over from python. The book I am reading is currently discussing breaks, which I am familiar with. When it comes to labeled breaks, can I give the label any name I choose (barring keywords)? Another thing, how do I end the scope of the label?

Note: The book didn't really specify. I am assuming yes but if there are any rules and guidelines that are different from standard naming conventions please let me know.

Comment: It has to be a valid identifier. `a1` is fine. `1a` is not.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you!

Comment: Note that, in 20 years of reading and writing Java code, I can't remember having found a single label in actual Java code. They're not considered as good practice, and nobody uses them.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the info. I'm learning to program as a 14 yo. Any recommended open source projects I should look at to improve both my style and habits?

Comment: @JBNizet I can't remember where, but I'm pretty sure I've seen labels in core Java/JavaFX libraries. Not often, mind you, but not zero either. That's not to say I think they're a good choice; I agree they should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can label your loops and then use labeled breaks:

```
outer: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    System.out.println(i + "," + j);
    break outer;
  }
}
```

Output will be `0,0`, since it breaks the outer loop on the first iteration of the inner loop.